# What is the Python equivalent of CPP reinterpret_cast

Tags: python

I got stuck in a trivial problem of `reinterpret_cast` casting operator. Basically, in CPP, I have a `float` variable which is used to create a `uint32_t` variable using `reinterpret_cast` as shown below-

```cpp
float x = 2.2949836e-38;
uint32_t rgb = *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&x);
printf("rgb=%d", rgb); // prints rgb=16377550
```

**I want to achieve the same in python. Please note that conventional int casting isn't producing the expected result.**

Comment: Do you want to achieve UB in python?

Comment: Whilst this looks like C++, it really isn't. The language *explicitly* chooses not to assign a meaning to that snippet.

Comment: Just for completeness... the "right" way to do this in C++ is `memcpy(&rgb, &x, sizeof(uint32_t))`.  It avoids aliasing, and the memcpy function call will get optimized away.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `pack`, `unpack` from `struct` module:

```
from struct import pack, unpack

b = pack('f', 2.2949836e-38)
print(unpack('i', b)[0])
```

Prints:

```
16377550
```

Edit:

shortened example